# Other than Quorum, what are some other Enterprise Ethereum-based platform available?

Tags: quorum

Other than Quorum, what are some other Enterprise Ethereum-based platform available out there?

Answer (score 1):

- [Monax](https://monax.io/).
- [Microsoft Azure and Ethereum](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/improved-multi-member-blockchain-networks-now-available-on-azure/)

Comment: Thanks! Can I run both in my private network?

Comment: Yes you can yes yes yes very annoying mininimum comment length

Comment: Thanks! I have tried it before with ethereum but not with monax.

Answer (score 1):

Pantheon by PegaSys (Consensys) is worth a look: https://pegasys.tech/

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to what the others have suggested...

- [Nightfall](https://github.com/EYBlockchain/nightfall), by EY
- JP Morgan:

  - [Tessera](https://github.com/jpmorganchase/tessera) - *"Enterprise Implementation of Quorum's transaction manager"*
  - [Cake Shop](https://github.com/jpmorganchase/cakeshop) - *"An integrated development environment and SDK for Ethereum*-*like ledgers"*
- [STRATO](https://blockapps.net/), by BlockApps